# Modify decimal to some binary numbers using Devtools

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I read an answer to a question (What is arbitrary precision integers) and the answer I read was

> The term fixed precision means that there are only a certain number of
> significant digits retained in the internal representation. This means
> that you would not be able to represent every integer with a magnitude
> greater than some threshold.
>
> With arbitrary precision integers, the integers can be as large as you
> need ("arbitrarily large") and the library will keep all the digits
> down to the least significant unit. (This is obviously limited by the
> amount of memory in your computer.)

I replaced a 443 decimal number with a 100 binary number, 100 was returned as the response, but I feel since decimal numbers and binary numbers aren't the same thing there should be a change on the response value. I know it'll be simple to some of you, but please teach me. I want to know and not be lost.

Comment: The quote talks about fixed precision vs arbitrary precision. You talk about decimal vs binary. What's the relation?

Comment: I’m just trying to Both Binary and Decimal aren’t Same… So idk what Happens if I replace it

Comment: When you replace a decimal number with a binary number, you now have a binary number. Apart from that, it's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: So computer system can’t read 100 As Binary still for a particular function When it’s Supposed to be read As a Decimal number?

Comment: Is there a way I could ask someone this question directly with my Voice OMg

Answer (score 0):

> So computer system can’t read 100 As Binary still for a particular function When it’s Supposed to be read As a Decimal number.

It depends from where you are reading the value and how it is stored.  Most command line input is in the form of a string and has to be converted to a type of number (an `int` or a `double` for example).  Whether the input is specified as binary, octal, or hex, its internal state will be the same and will be binary. (In fact, everything on your hard disk is stored as binary).  For doubles, they too will be binary but are stored in a specific format/encoding (see [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).  Java doubles are floating point values.  They are 64 bits wide and both the integral part and the fractional part can vary in size, but together, along with the size and exponent, they can't exceed 64 bits.  So if you have a very large integral part, there won't be much room left for the fractional part (and vice versa).  Ints are 32 bits wide with the high order bit used for the sign.  They are stored in [Two's complement form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  There is more to this than explained here so I recommend you try and find more detailed information on the internal representation of numeric types.

**Updated.**

```
int a = 443;
int b = 100; // not binary it's 100 in decimal
System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

prints

```
443 100
```

```
int a = 0b100;  // binary. Leading 0b. Value is 4
int b = 0100;   // octal.  Leading 0.  value is 64
int c = 0x100;  // hex. Leading 0x. value is 256  
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

prints

```
4 64 256
```

Also

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(a,2)); // second arg is output base (or radix)
System.out.println(Integer.toString(b,8));
System.out.println(Integer.toString(c,16));
```

prints

```
100
100
100
```

Comment: I don’t know if it’s recommended to get your WhatsApp or Any other social Media so we could solve the problem Together Please

Comment: The site does not work that way.  You ask a question and maybe it gets answered; if the question isn't clear enough to answer, refine the questiion until is.